# Product Search php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search, product

Im trying to create a search for a product from the database.

MY DB:

```
tbl_brand
-----------
brand_id Brand_name
1        Canon
2        Nikon

tbl_product
-------------
prod_id  prod_name                                                    brand_id
1        Canon PowerShot A810 16MP Point & Shoot Digital Camera       1
2        Canon Digital Camera PowerShot 8MP Point & Shoot             1
3        PowerShot 8MP Point & Shoot Digital Camera                   1
4        PowerShot 8MP Point & Shoot Digital                          1
```

My Keyword for search :

1. `$keyword = 'Camera';`
2. `$keyword = 'Digital Camera';`
3. `$keyword = 'Canon Digital Camera';`
4. `$keyword = 'Canon Camera';`

my query

```
Select * from tbl_product where prod_name like '%$keyword%'
```

I get results for first three keywords. But for 4th keyword i get results empty.

Canon Camera - keyword does not match the product name. But all the products are under canon brand only and all the products are camera only.

I need to show all the products for 'Canon Camera' keyword . I am newbie for php and mysql. Kindly help in this.

Comment: This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621310/php-sql-select-where-like-search-item-with-multiple-words

Answer (score 7):

try this with `MATCH .. AGAINST`

Here's how to get it to work:

1. First make sure your table uses the MyISAM storage engine.  MySQL FULLTEXT indexes support only MyISAM tables.  (**edit 11/1/2012:** MySQL 5.6 is introducing a FULLTEXT index type for InnoDB tables.)

   ```
   ALTER TABLE tbl_product ENGINE=MyISAM;
   ```
2. Create a fulltext index.

   ```
   CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX searchindex ON tbl_product(prod_name);
   ```
3. Search it!

   ```
   $keyword = mysql_real_escape_string($keyword);
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_product 
       WHERE MATCH(prod_name) AGAINST('$keyword')");
   ```

   Note that the columns you name in the `MATCH` clause *must* be the same columns in the same order as those you declared in the fulltext index definition.  Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:-

```
$keywords = explode(' ', $keyword);
$searchTermKeywords = array();
foreach ($keywords as $word) 
{

$searchTermKeywords[] = "prod_name LIKE '%$word%'";

}

$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $searchTermKeywords).");
```

Explanation:-
In this code i am splitting the search keywords using space and storing it into array. After that i am adding the sql string to an array. The no. of elements will depend on the number of search terms entered by the user. In the mysql_query function i am imploding the array with AND which after execution will look like(for 'digital camera' keyword):-

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE prod_name LIKE '%digital%' AND prod_name LIKE '%camera%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$keywords = explode(' ', $keyword);
foreach($keywords as $words) {
$x++
if($x == 1) {
    $searchterm .= "prod_name LIKE %$words%";
}else {
    $searchterm .= " OR prod_name LIKE %$words%";
}
}
Select * from tbl_product where prod_name like '%$searchterm%';
```

it will search for each word u typed

Comment: what is the use of $x++

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't have 'Canon Camera' in the database :) Your code is totally fine. With this search %'Canon Camera'% you can have everything before and after the string, but you MUST have the exact string 'Canon Camera' in the middle.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php include "header.php"; ?>

        <div id="page-wrapper">

            <div class="container-fluid">

                <!-- Page Heading -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                         <?php
$query = $_GET['query']; 
    $min_length = 1;
  if(strlen($query) >= $min_length)
  { 
        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
        $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $query);  

  echo "<h4>Your match result(s) for <font color=#B22222>$query</font></h4>
  <hr>";
  //select 2 tables - search
  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT category_name, image, category_id, datetime, description, category_id FROM category 
  WHERE (`category_name` LIKE '%" .$query. "%') 
  UNION SELECT product_name, image, product_id, datetime, description, category_id FROM products WHERE (`product_name` LIKE '%" .$query. "%' )
  UNION SELECT username, fname, lname, email, contact, user_id FROM users WHERE (`username` LIKE '%" .$query. "%' )
  ") or die(mysqli_error()); 


        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {
            while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   { 
        echo "";  ?>

        <?php Print ""  ?>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <a href="#">
                    <img width="280" height="250" src="<?php echo $info['image']; ?>" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
               <?php 
        if (strpos($info, '') === true)

        {  Print "<h4><a href='view_cat.php?category_id=".$info['category_id']."'>".$info['category_name']."</a></h4>";  }

    else if (strpos($query, 'username') === true)
    { Print "<h4><a href='view_cat.php?category_id=".$info['category_id']."'>".$info['username']."</a></h4>"; }



               ?>
                <hr>
                <h4>Added at: <?php echo date("d-M-Y", strtotime($info['datetime'])); ?></h4>
                <h4>Description: <?php echo $info['description']; ?></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php "";

            }

           }
        else { 
            echo "<p>
            <img src='../image/alert.png'><br />
            <h4>Sorry... No results for $query</h4>"; 
   echo "";  
        }   
    }
    else{ 
        echo "<h4>Search empty field. Please input your category name</h4>";
    }
?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->

            </div>`enter code here`
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->

        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->`enter code here`

<?php include "footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: so what's the problem?

Answer (score -2):

```
$keywords = str_replace(' ','%',$keywords);
Select * from tbl_product where prod_name like '%$keyword%'
```

Answer (score -2):

You may try this...

```
$keyword = 'Canon Camera';
$keys = explode(" ",$keyword);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE ";

//$wheresql = "prod_name LIKE '".$keyword."'";
$wheresql = "1=2 OR ";

foreach ($keys as $key) {
$wheresql .= " OR prod_name LIKE '".$key."' ";
}
print_r($sql.$wheresql);
```