# PHP MySql E-Commerce left column filter results

Tags: php, mysql, filter

Ok i've been looking for ages now and cannot find anything to help me and i've tried a couple of my own ways with stupidly bad results.

All I want is to have a left column that filters through my product results.

So, if I have all of my products on the page I then click a brand/catagory/sub catagory on the left column and it will filter the products to match, except I would like to be able to click on more than just one filter as to define the results even further (just like they do on every e-commerce website).

Comment: you're to use ajax on this.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Answer (score 0):

You can have many options for your search. My suggestion would be using infinite scroll with ajax search and range selector. As per your request choosing multiple brands in the leftsidebar and then setting the range for products will be achieved by joining some of the jquery plugins.

There are many options you can choose from some links are listed below you can refer them.

http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/03/infinite-scrolling-get-bottom/

http://jqueryui.com/slider/

[Product Search php mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692323/product-search-php-mysql)

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but all the same it's most welcome, I can research these more and implement where needed in future websites, thank you.

Except for the product search php mysql, I already have that :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for this is by settint GET variables when a filter is clicked. For ex if you are on a listing page for a category (ex. /category1) and a manufacturer or brand or whatever filter is clicked you just redirect to /category1?brand=4 or brand=brand_name depending on whether you use ids or names. Than when you constructyour query for the category listing hou'll have to concstenate filters like so:
$sql ='select * from products where category_id='.$category; and then check with isset if any of the existing filters have been selected this way:
If(isset($_GET['brand'])) $sql .= ' and brand_id = '.$_GET['brand']; and so on for the other filters.
Sorry for possible typos im writing this from my phone. Hope it helps you.