# How to implement search feature along with filters in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have multiple columns from which I have to search the things. Columns are like title and description etc. To do it, I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19612291/4547783)

But with this search, I need other filters as well like 'city' and 'category'. My modified solution is as follows:

```
if(isset($search_term))
    {
        $search_terms = explode(' ', $search_term);

        $fields = array('title', 'description');

        foreach ($search_terms as $term)
        {
           foreach ($fields as $field)
            {
               $cases = $cases->orWhere($field, 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
            }

        }

      if (count($cases) == 0)
        $cases = NULL;

    }

if (isset($categoryID))
    {
        $cases = $cases->where('category_ID','=', $categoryID);

        }

    if (isset($cityID))
    {
        $cases = $cases->where('city_ID','=', $cityID);

    }
```

The results of this code are not specific to search term. It is showing all the results. The problem I identified is orWhere() method in my case. Is it? What alternative can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is as follows:

```
    if(isset($search_term))
        {
            $search_terms = explode(' ', $search_term);

            $fields = array('id', 'title', 'case');

            $cases = $cases->where(function($q) use ($search_terms, $fields){
                    foreach ($search_terms as $term)
                    {
                       foreach ($fields as $field)
                        {
                           $q->orWhere($field, 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
                        }

                    }
            });

         }

if (isset($categoryID))
    {
        $cases = $cases->where('category_ID','=', $categoryID);

        }

    if (isset($cityID))
    {
        $cases = $cases->where('city_ID','=', $cityID);

    }
```

In this code first of all orWhere is performed then the result will be ANDed with 'city' and 'category' filter.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

What you are looking for is method-chaining on a query.

Let's say, you are searching on an Eloquent Class `Cases`

Your code will then be:

```
//This creates an object ready for queries on the DB
$caseQuery = Cases::query();

//Add conditions -- START

if(isset($search_term))
{
    $search_terms = explode(' ', $search_term);

    $fields = array('title', 'description');

    foreach ($search_terms as $term)
    {
       foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
           $caseQuery->orWhere($field, 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
        }

    }
}

if (isset($categoryID))
{
    $caseQuery->where('category_ID','=', $categoryID,'AND');
}

if (isset($cityID))
{
    $caseQuery->where('city_ID','=', $cityID,'AND');

}

//Add Conditions -- END

//Fetch results

$caseResult = $caseQuery->get();


//Get Number of Results
$resultCount = $caseQuery->count();
```

**Suggestion:**

This is an adaptive solution at best.

You need a native solution for searches and i'll like to point you towards ElasticSearch.

Elasticsearch is an open-source search engine, based on Java. All of its API is available through REST endpoints.

The advantage of using a search engine is that it will sort your results according to *relevance*. SQL queries will just return all that's matching.

ElasticSearch: https://www.elastic.co/

Excellent PHP package Elastica for Elasticsearch: http://elastica.io/

Comment: For proper `LIKE` queries to work, make sure you have `fulltext` indexes on your sql table.