# SQL search for a string like with combination of sub-string of a String string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query for getting hospital names list similar to the entering text. The entering text is `$address`

```
SELECT address FROM hospital WHERE address LIKE '%$address%'
```

My table contains hospital "Government Medical College Kozhikode"

Result is success while entering following texts

> Government
>
> Government Medical
>
> Government Medical College
>
> Government Medical College Kozhikode

But result is empty when entering following texts

> Kozhikode Government Medical College
>
> Kozhikode Medical College

How can i replace my query?

I want to search for the hospital name which is likely to the combination of sub-string (in any order) of searching word.

For example I want to get

> "QWERTY Hospital Kozhikode"

When searching

> "QWERTY Hospital Kozhikode"
>
> "Kozhikode QWERTY Hospital"
>
> "Kozhikode Hospital QWERTY"
>
> "Hospital QWERTY Kozhikode"
>
> "Hospital Kozhikode QWERTY"

Comment: How about splitting the entered text by spaces and then create dynamic where clauses using `or condition` for each of the words? but 1 question, do you still want to get the result for searching for "Government Medical College Kozhikode" when you provide this string: "Kozhikode Government Medical College Hospital "?

Comment: Use REGEXP - see below.

Comment: @mitkosoft I want the result like__________SELECT address FROM hospital WHERE address LIKE '%QWERTY%' AND address LIKE '%Hospital%' AND address LIKE '%Kozhikode%'  _______  but your RE results_________ SELECT address FROM hospital WHERE address LIKE '%QWERTY%' OR address LIKE '%Hospital%' OR address LIKE '%Kozhikode%'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First trim any white spaces:

```
$address = trim($address);
```

Then simply use REGEXP in your query:

If you want to be `OR LIKE`, use following:

```
SELECT address FROM hospital WHERE address REGEXP REPLACE('$address',' ','|')
```

This is 'converting' your multiwords string into `OR LIKE '%%'` parts.

If you want to be `AND LIKE`, use following:

```
SELECT address FROM hospital WHERE address REGEXP REPLACE('$address',' ','.+')
```

This is 'converting' your multiwords string into `AND LIKE '%%'` parts.

More about REGEXP here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-regexps.htm

Comment: My requirement is '&' in case or '|' . How can i represent it?

Comment: This is showing "Chest Hospital Kozhikode" also while searching "QWERTY Hospital Kozhikode". I think it is due to the "OR"

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. New everything is fine. There is a chance of error due to duplication or '|' or '.+' symbol  if last character is white space. So I have added the trim statement for avoiding it.

Comment: @VinilChandran, If this answer has helped you solve your problem, please select it as the most useful answer...

Answer (score 0):

You could split your search query on spaces and then craft a query like:

ANY of the words:

```
SELECT address FROM hospital WHERE address LIKE '%QWERTY%' OR address LIKE '%Hospital%' OR address LIKE '%Kozhikode%'
```

ALL of the words:

```
SELECT address FROM hospital WHERE address LIKE '%QWERTY%' AND address LIKE '%Hospital%' AND address LIKE '%Kozhikode%'
```

It would not be efficient for large tables though.

Otherwise I would suggest looking into the FULLTEXT index in MySQL, which would allow you to search for one or several words in your texts. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html

Comment: QWERTY Hospital Kozhikode is just an example. Actually it's a variable

Comment: Yeah, I was just reusing the example you provided. Have you tried splitting on spaces and building your request that way?

Comment: My main requirement is to split that word in to sub-string using MySQL ;-), I can use PHP to split and make a query separately. Bu think its not a good method. That's why asked.

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621310/php-sql-select-where-like-search-item-with-multiple-words).

Just loop on your word and add a "WHERE name="%?%" for each word, it will now behave like you wanted to :)