# The search box on my website always search only for the last words of the entered sentence

Tags: php, full-text-search

I recently added search box to search certain data on my database.
Im using php LIKE function.for the first time when i use LIKE function it took only one word and if that match any of contents then the results came out.and if i type more than one word it came zero results and it return a error that "No results".
And as i did a research i made my code it to thing.(Now it is allways searching only for the last word on the sentence that we enter for search.)]
In a example :

If type "car for sell" the query going to search for "Sell" .If there are any records match the query then it will exicutue (weather it is car or any other data.)

what i want to do iss to let it search for complete search where it matchs in the database.

For a example :

if i want to find "car for sell"
i want the query to execute only cars for sell in my cars category and so on.

here are my codes.

```
$getquery = $_GET['query'];

if(isset($_GET['query'])){

        $getquery = $_GET['query'];
        $queryexplode = explode(" ", $getquery);
            foreach($queryexplode as $queryexplodenew){
                $meta = $queryexplodenew;   
            }

    $getdataquery = "SELECT `AdName`, `AdAccessLink`, `timestamp`, `Country`, `Category`, `Price`, `Photo1name` FROM freeadpostingdata WHERE AdName LIKE '%$queryexplodenew%' OR Country LIKE '%$queryexplodenew%' OR Category LIKE '%$queryexplodenew%' OR AdDescription LIKE '%$queryexplodenew%' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 25";
    $resultsgetdata = mysql_query($getdataquery);
    $countprodu= mysql_num_rows($resultsgetdata);

    }
```

please help me to get this solved. 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for your code, it will always search for the last word.

```
$getquery = $_GET['query'];
$modifiedKeyword = explode(" ", $getquery);
$str = implode("', '", $modifiedKeyword );
```

And change your query like the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM your_table WHERE keyword IN ('$str')";
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: i just modified it.its nothing anything happen now.

Comment: $getquery = $_GET['query'];
   $getquery = $_GET['query'];
$queryexplode = explode(" ", $getquery);
$modifiedKeyword = implode("', '", $queryexplode);
   
  $getdataquery = "SELECT `AdName`, `AdAccessLink`, `timestamp`, `Country`, `Category`, `Price`, `Photo1name` FROM freeadpostingdata WHERE AdName IN ('$modifiedKeyword') OR Country IN ('$modifiedKeyword') OR Category IN ('$modifiedKeyword') OR AdDescription IN ('$modifiedKeyword') ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 25";

Comment: your codes are fine when i checked them on sql prompt.But it was also said zero results

Comment: @LeoneMaleash Does it mean, sql query is working at phpmyadmin but not at php code?

Comment: No i meant codes does not brinmg any arrors.its only dosnt working.Do you have any suggestion for this ?

Comment: Would you share the generate SQL?

Comment: im sorry ,I missed it and moved to the old one. I can share my working old query.but it is also searching for the last word of the search box.

Comment: I have edited my answer once again. If this time does work then please print here the exact query.

Comment: it is not still working with your new codes. 
if(isset($_GET['query'])){
   
   $getquery = $_GET['query'];
$modifiedKeyword = explode(" ", $getquery);
$str = implode(",", $modifiefKeyword);
   
  $getdataquery = "SELECT `AdName`, `AdAccessLink`, `timestamp`, `Country`, `Category`, `Price`, `Photo1name` FROM freeadpostingdata WHERE AdName IN ('$str') ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 25";
  $resultsgetdata = mysql_query($getdataquery);
  $countprodu= mysql_num_rows($resultsgetdata);

  }

Comment: @LeoneMaleash I have edited and tested the code. I hope this time it will work.

Comment: it is same.it say no results found for the keyword i enter

Comment: $getquery = $_GET['query'];
$modifiedKeyword = explode(" ", $getquery);
$str = implode("', '", $modifiedKeyword );
   
  $getdataquery = "SELECT `AdName`, `AdAccessLink`, `timestamp`, `Country`, `Category`, `Price`, `Photo1name` FROM freeadpostingdata WHERE AdName IN ('$str') OR Country IN ('$str') OR Category IN ('$str') OR AdDescription IN ('$str') ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 25";
  $resultsgetdata = mysql_query($getdataquery);
  $countprodu= mysql_num_rows($resultsgetdata);




here are my codes

Comment: i just checked the code.in mysql it also said this erro

Comment: Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Ending quote " was expected. (near "" at position 251)
SQL query: Documentation

SELECT `AdName`, `AdAccessLink`, `timestamp`, `Country`, `Category`, `Price`, `Photo1name` FROM freeadpostingdata WHERE AdName IN ('$str') OR Country IN ('$str') OR Category IN ('$str') OR AdDescription IN ('$str') ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 25"

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"' at line 1

Comment: @LeoneMaleash can you please print $getdataquery with exact values, not with any php vars inside the query, ok?

Comment: i didnt get you sorry ?

Comment: this is the correct one im using and it is working ,but only for last word of the content

$getdataquery = "SELECT `AdName`, `AdAccessLink`, `timestamp`, `Country`, `Category`, `Price`, `Photo1name` FROM freeadpostingdata WHERE AdName LIKE '%$queryexplodenew%' OR Country LIKE '%$queryexplodenew%' OR Category LIKE '%$queryexplodenew%' OR AdDescription LIKE '%$queryexplodenew%' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 25";

Comment: do echo($getdataquery) and copy here the echoed text.

Comment: SELECT `AdName`, `AdAccessLink`, `timestamp`, `Country`, `Category`, `Price`, `Photo1name` FROM freeadpostingdata WHERE AdName LIKE '%sell%' OR Country LIKE '%sell%' OR Category LIKE '%sell%' OR AdDescription LIKE '%sell%' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 25

Comment: i searched for car for sell.But it has searched only  for "sell"

Comment: I was expecting echoed output of $getdataquery = "SELECT AdName, AdAccessLink, timestamp, Country, Category, Price, Photo1name FROM freeadpostingdata WHERE AdName IN ('$str') OR Country IN ('$str') OR Category IN ('$str') OR AdDescription IN ('$str') ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 25";  after my last correction.

Comment: here are the echoed statement

Comment: SELECT `AdName`, `AdAccessLink`, `timestamp`, `Country`, `Category`, `Price`, `Photo1name` FROM freeadpostingdata WHERE AdName IN ('car', 'for', 'sell') OR Country IN ('car', 'for', 'sell') OR Category IN ('car', 'for', 'sell') OR AdDescription IN ('car', 'for', 'sell') ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0, 25

Comment: This query looks correct. Now my observation says, none of the fields have the unique information rather it has with more text. I mean, no single value with car or for or sell at either fields. I hope you got it.

Comment: No.Its wrong,Because i have a field in my database like this "honda car for sell" , and i searched this thing. But it was same.

Or can you help me to write "Match Against Mysql " ??
I think that is what exactly can help me ? Do you

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621310/php-sql-select-where-like-search-item-with-multiple-words where for each field like query is built. I hope it will help you a lot.

Comment: @LeoneMaleash if there is only word "honda" and you search with 'honda my car' then you will get the result with my code ok? And I have mentioned another solution in my previous comments.

Comment: Thank you i think i got the impression, i can go ahead. Thank you very much for your support.And you codes are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are only searching for the last word is because of this:

```
    $queryexplode = explode(" ", $getquery);
        foreach($queryexplode as $queryexplodenew){
            $meta = $queryexplodenew;   
        }
```

You are iterating over each word in the query with each word being put in `$queryexplodenew` in turn (and then assigned to `$meta` for some reason). When the loop completes, the thing in `$queryexplodenew` will be the last element iterated over.